# PayU POST notification signature validation

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, payu

I'm integrating PayU API service in my web (.NET MVC Core 2.1) application.
After client pays order, PayU sends notification confirmation as POST request to my api method.

[Example](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#update_notification_for_order_status) of PayU confirmation notification.

In heareds notification placed MD5 signature.

```
OpenPayu-Signature:
                sender=checkout;
                signature=c33a38d89fb60f873c039fcec3a14743;
                algorithm=MD5;
                content=DOCUMENT
```

```
string incoming_signature = c33a38d89fb60f873c039fcec3a14743;
```

What I supposed to do to verify that notification:

[Here](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#references_verification_of_notifications_signature) is instruction to verify notification signature.

1.Combine the body of the incoming notification with the value of second_key(second key is avaliable in my account page in payu ):

```
string concatenated = JSONnotification + second_key;
```

2.Select an expected signature value by applying the hashing function (e.g. md5) in the received chain of characters:

```
string expected_signature = md5(concatenated)
```

3.Compare the strings: expected_signature and incoming_signature:

```
bool signature_is_correct = (expected_signature == incoming_signature);
```

***Problem is checksums is not matching.***

I Handle this notification in my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("notify")]
public IActionResult TransactionConfirm([FromBody] dynamic content)
```

`content` variable parsed as a `object`

and I accessing JsonBody string as `content.ToString()`
method.

Is it possible to hashes isn't matched because method content.ToString() can return not the same string like in request body?

Is there any ways to handle json as argument in .Net Core method? (I've already tried to placed JObject, but method ToString() also returned string that generated to hash isn't matching)

Answer (score 0):

To compute a matching hash, you need to read the incoming request as is, without deserializing it. So yes, your generated JSON probably differs from the sent one (whitespace characters).

I'm not really familiar with ASP.NET Core, but in the old ASP.NET, you could read the request content using:

```
var json = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```